# Creating a product set on Google Vision API

Tags: computer-vision, google-vision, google-ai-platform

We are currently trying to customize the Google Vision API for our iOS mobile app.

We manage the workflow with the phyton shell.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4aBNt.png)
Using bulk import to create a product set with products,
we started to upload the 69 CSV-files (around 150 mB) to the system.

And then, all files have status "processing" for about 6 days. 6 days!
is it ok?

There is no detailed information about the process or the processing steps anywhere.

Can anyone advise if this is a normal situation, that we are waiting so long?
Or maybe we are not doing something wrong?

I will be grateful for any help!